# docx generation: putting elements inside ffData (CTFFData)

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, docx, docx4j

I'm using docx4j library to generate a docx file. I need to put couple of other elements inside the `w:ffData` tag, eventually creating a structure like this:

```
<w:ffData>
  <w:name w:val="Some value"/>
  <w:enabled/>
  <w:calcOnExit w:val="0"/>
  <w:checkBox>
    <w:sizeAuto/>
    <w:default w:val="0"/>
    <w:checked/>
  </w:checkBox>
</w:ffData>
```

I can successfully create the `w:ffData` element using

```
CTFFData  ffData =  factory.createCTFFData();
```

Now, being a total docx4j newbie I'd expect a `getContent` method as is for example available for the `R` class (produces `w:r` elements).

Having no such a method at my disposal, I'm looking for other approaches to this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclosure: I'm docx4j project lead **

A getContent method is a reasonable expectation, but for CTFFData, there is just the inelegantly named but otherwise equivalent:

```
public List<JAXBElement<?>> getNameOrEnabledOrCalcOnExit()
```